# Display Events on PHP Calendar

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I would like to ask if I have a table of events on my database, e.g.

```
description | startdt             | enddt
event1      | 2010-04-01 10:00:00 | 2010-04-01 13:00:00
event2      | 2010-04-09 14:00:00 | 2010-04-09 18:00:00
event3      | 2010-04-30 11:00:00 | 2010-05-02 16:00:00
```

I have already created a php calendar, how can I display these above events onto my calendar, so that it will look something like the google calendar? e.g. on the  for 2010-04-01, it will display "event1" on the month calendar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got a $year and $month variable already precomputed for displaying the calendar grid, you'd fetch the data from the database something like this:

```
$query = <<<EOF
SELECT DAY(startdt) AS day, description
FROM table
WHERE (YEAR(startdt) = $year) AND (MONTH(startdt) = $month)
EOF;

$stmt = mysql_query($query) or die ('Query error: ' . mysql_error());

$events = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
   $events[$row['day']][] = $row['description']; // might have multiple events on one day, so store as an array of events
}
```

Then while building the calendar, check if $day is present in the `$events` array and output the descriptions however you wish:

```
for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
    if(isset($events[$day])) {
         ... display event descriptions
    }
}
```

Of course, if you have events that span multiple days, then you'll have to modify things to handle that, but this should get you started with at least single-day events.